# Magento addFieldToFilter allow NULLs

Tags: magento

When using the Magento collection method addFieldToFilter is it possible to allow filtering by NULL values? I want to select all the products in a collection that have a custom attribute even if no value is assigned to the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `addFieldToFilter`.

**now the solution:** 
attributes name is known as `code` in magento, you just need to use the code below to get all of the products which have a specific attribute as an array

```
$prodsArray=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute_code')
                                  ->getItems();
```

you can also specify certain conditions for attribute's value in `addAttributeToFilter` in the second parameter of addAttributeToFilter.

you can find this method in this file (for further study):

```
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out addFieldToFilter - it led to the solution of handling NULL fields

Comment: this is actually wrong, this will do a comparison with empty '' rather than a "is null" filtering.

Answer (score 56):

I see you already found a solution, but there is also this option:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id', array('null' => true));
```

But if you want to use "NULL" =>  false, which DOESN'T WORK.
(and I noticed you can use elements such as "in", "nin", "eq", "neq", "gt"), you can do this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id', array('neq' => 'NULL' ));
```

Hope this is still helpful...

Comment: See documentation in code of Varien_Data_Collection_Db::_getConditionSql(). It describes all options that are possible, like the mentioned 'null', but also 'notnull' for the reverse.

Answer (score 26):

This works for NOT NULL filters

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id', array('notnull' => true));
```

Answer (score 19):

Filtering a product collection by null/empty attributes has two possible solutions. Magento uses an INNER JOIN to grab the values of the attributes to filter. BUT if the product attribute is not assigned a value the join will fail, as a database table / relationship is missing.

**Solution #1:** Use addAttributeToFilter() and change the join type from "inner" (the default) to "left":

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', array( ... condition options ..), 'left');
```

**Solution #2:** Make sure your custom attribute has a default value. Magento is conservative in this regard. Magento will only create the relationship between an attribute and a product if a value is given for the attribute. So in the absence of user-specified value or a default value the attribute will not be accessible for filtering a product *even if the attribute appears in the product detail view under the admin panel.*

Comment: Left join is a must when grabbing attribute, IMO.

Answer (score 7):

Because the question does not match exactly the title of the question and I found the them multiple times by searching for a condition like: special VALUE OR NULL

If you want to filter a collection matching a VALUE OR NULL, then you can use:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('<attribute>', array(
  array('eq' => '<value>'),
  array('null' => true)
));
```